# Leaflet: Dynamic div container

Tags: javascript, css, svg, leaflet

I'm trying to create a small example using Leaflet and use it on my web app, however I'm having some dificulties.

I already made a standalone Leaflet example from the [quick start guide](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/examples/quick-start.html) of their page, which has a static map div and overlays a few objects (`marker`, `circle` and `polygon`).
However in my app, the map div container is positioned and sized dynamically with jquery, and it's a pretty complex app so I can't post here the whole code.

The problem is that after the correct processing of the div the map is drawn correctly in the div (wherever it is), however in the overlays layer I can only see the `marker`. The `circle` and `polygon`are not visible.

```
    var map = L.map(this.$el.attr('id')).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/<APIKEY>/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
        maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);

    var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).addTo(map);

    var polygon = L.polygon([
        [51.509, -0.08],
        [51.503, -0.06],
        [51.51, -0.047]
    ]).addTo(map);

    var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.");
    circle.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.").openPopup();
```

I believe there's nothing wrong in the way I create the map and objects and I even call `map.invalidateSize()` after the whole resizing of the div. And the curious part is that the popup is shown in the correct position, but no circle behind it.

Could the problem be in the way I resize and position the div containers. Is there any specific `CSS` property I should be using in the div container?

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sleeping on this problem I thought about making a `JSFiddle` example to reproduce the issue.
However no matter how hard I tried I couldn't replicate the issue in a simpler standalone example, so the problem had to be in some conflict within my app.

Every symptom pointed to a `CSS` problem, however my `CSS` was well scoped.
So my last theory was that it had to be a conflict in some library I was using.

It turned out to be correct. The problem was a conflict in the `CSS` stylesheet of the library [NVD3](http://nvd3.com/)